# Convert from PKCS1 to PKCS8 in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using a C# google SDK to access Google Drive and GMail.  For authentication, sometimes I'm provided a PKCS8 private key and other times it is a PKCS1 private key.  I can make the PKCS8 authentication work, since that is what Google SDK expects.  However, when I attempt to convert the PKCS1 into a PKCS8...it seems to work at first, until I actually start to make invocations against google's API.

Based on [this advice](https://vcsjones.dev/key-formats-dotnet-3/), here is the code I'm using that is designed to receive PKCS1 or PKCS8:

```CSharp
string pkcs8Key = null;
if (creds.PrivateKey.Contains("BEGIN RSA"))
{
    // Handle PKCS1
    var keyParts = creds.PrivateKey.Split("-----", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var rawKey = keyParts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
    var base64Key = rawKey.Trim();

    var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key);
    using var privateKey = RSA.Create();
    privateKey.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);
    var keyBytes = privateKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
    pkcs8Key = $"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----{Convert.ToBase64String(keyBytes)}-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
}
else
{
    // Handle PKCS8
    pkcs8Key = creds.PrivateKey;
}

initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(creds.ID)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly, DriveService.Scope.Drive },
            User = email ?? creds.AdminAccount,
            KeyId = creds.PrivateKeyId,
            ProjectId = creds.ProjectId
        }.FromPrivateKey(pkcs8Key))
};
```

Although the code above runs successfully, the error I receive later when I make an SDK request is this:

```
 Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"java.security.SignatureException: Invalid signature for token: **JWT Suppressed**", Uri:""
```

I found [this article](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) which talks about causes of google's "invalid grant," and "reason #9" concerns me...because it seems to suggest that my token is indeed malformed, which would correspond with the "invalid signature" the error mentioned.  Still, I'm not sure if I'm comparing apples to apples.

Any ideas?

Perhaps the problem is simply that the PKCS1 private key I'm using...doesn't have sufficient privileges?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had two sets of credentials to experiment with:

- PKCS#1 private RSA key
- PKCS#8 private key: Associated with this, I also had a "Private key id" and "project id"

Since both private keys pertained to the same service client email, I had been supplying the (otherwise optional) "private key id" and "project id" values for either private key above.

All I had to do was intentionally omit the "private key id" and "project id", when I was processing the PKCS#1, and then it worked.  This leaves me still wondering what purpose those optional values serve...though I suspect it pertains to security audits (e.g. auth logs).